# How many chicks can my cockatiel take care of?

Tags: cockatiels

First time chick mom. Not planned. How many chicks can the couple raise?

Comment: Do you want to know how many chicks a pair get in common case, or how much they can care for at the same time, or how often they can breed in a healthy manner?